# Formating user input to match stored values

Tags: javascript

I have an H3 element that I'm currently using to initialize a game

```
<h3 id="startGame">Start</h3>
```

The following is the JavaScript that I've written

In the function `formatText()` I take what the user has inputted and make the entire string lower case.  I then capitalize the first letter of the word so that it matches how the strings are written in the array.  In the case where there is actually two words, I then grab the first letter of the second word and capitalize that to match the way the two word strings are written in the array.

In the end when a user inputs what I've asked them to input, it shouldn't matter how they wrote it (in regards to capitalization).  All that should matter is that they spelled it right.

However, my problem is that it works for the one word strings but does not capitalize the second word as I intended.  Meaning I can enter the one word strings in any manner I wish (spelled correctly of course) and it will resolve to correct.  I can even input the two word strings and mess with the capitalization of the first word and it will resolve to correct.  However when I do not capitalize the second word it always resolves to incorrect.

The code that I've written to resolve this issue doesn't seem to work and I don't know why.

```
    var nutrients = [
    "Vitamin B6",
    "Manganese",
    "Vitamin C",
    "Fiber",
    "Potassium",
    "Biotin",
    "Copper"

];

function memoNutri() {

    var pleaseCopy;
    var spaceMarker = " ";
    var capitalizeSecondWord;
    var firstWord;
    var secondWord;
    var twoWords;

    function ask() {
        pleaseCopy = prompt("Enter the following into the text field: " + nutrients[i] + ".");
    }

    function formatText() {
        pleaseCopy.toLowerCase();

        pleaseCopy = pleaseCopy[0].toUpperCase() + pleaseCopy.substring(1, pleaseCopy.length);

        capitalizeSecondWord = pleaseCopy.substring(spaceMarker + 1, spaceMarker + 2).toUpperCase();

        firstWord = pleaseCopy.substring(0, spaceMarker);

        secondWord = capitalizeSecondWord + pleaseCopy.substring(spaceMarker + 2, pleaseCopy.length);

        twoWords = firstWord + spaceMarker + secondWord;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < nutrients.length; i++) {

        ask();

        formatText();

        if (pleaseCopy === nutrients[i] || twoWords === nutrients[i]) {
            alert("You are correct! " + nutrients[i]);
        } else {
            alert("That is incorrect");

        }
    }



    }

    var startGame = document.getElementById('startGame');
    startGame.onclick = memoNutri;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
var textArr = pleaseCopy.split(" ");

for (var i = 0; i < textArr.length; i++) {
    textArr[i] = textArr[i][0].toUpperCase() + textArr[i].substring(1).toLowerCase();
}

var twoWords = textArr.join(" ");
```

Split the content into an array. Format the text at each index, and the re-join the text.